How to use Nuxt Hooks? [VUE/NUXT]
im learning NUXT and i have a problem now.
I'm trying to use hooks in module, but i dont know how, because official documentation dont have any information about using hooks with composition api. I tried to make plugin, but i didnt find how to take value from this plugin or how to call this plugin in code.
And btw i guess regular Lifecycle VUE Hooks can't be used in Nuxt?
I'm trying to make Loading indicator and trying to use hook "page:loading:end".
I hope I wrote it clearly because I'm not Englishman :)

This page explains how to use Nuxt hooks:
If you create a plugin in ~/plugins/your-plugin.js it will be automatically imported by Nuxt.
Then you can use hooks:
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
               // Replace 'page:start' by whatever you want 
  nuxtApp.hook('page:start', () => {
    /* your code goes here */
  })
})

